# How to fade an edge in Cytoscape.JS?

Tags: cytoscape.js

In Cytoscape.JS graph with a few edges, how can I fade just one of my edges?
Is there some thing in style tag that does this?

Comment: Cytoscape.Js is drawing graphs using canvas. So you can not change it using styletag. you have to change your drawing data points so that it will not be drawn few edges.

Comment: @sandyJoshi Thank you but I want to fade (for example to 50%) some edges rather not drawing them.

Comment: @QandA Have you found a solution in the answers or by yourself? (You can always answer your own questions and close the topic afterwards) Do you need extra information? Just saying in the case you forgot to close this topic :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the opacity of a node or edge when you create the cytoscape canvas, using the style option.

From the [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/property-types): 
Opacity values are specified as numbers ranging on 0 <= opacity <= 1.

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  // your options
  container: /* ... */,
  elements: [ /* ... */ ],
  style: [ edge.opacity: 0.5 /* ... */ ],
  // ...
)}
```

If you want to change the opacity of an edge when you click a button (or whatever trigger you need) a style file for your canvas may be better. There you can setup a "faded class" for your edges and it to the edges whenever your button is clicked.

```
//Cytoscape-CSS
edge.faded {
 opacity: 0.5 /* 50% opacity */
}

//JS
edges.addClass('faded');
```

This [example](http://www.wineandcheesemap.com/) fades the nodes and edges of everything that's not in the [closed neighborhood](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.neighborhood) of the selected node. You can find its source code [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/wineandcheesemap).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be [cy.animate()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.animate):

```
yourElement.animation({
  style: { 'opacity': yourOpacity },
  duration: yourDuration
}).play();
```